# How to keep track of and update a value in a recursive function?

Tags: ruby, recursion

[image]

Above is a C++ function and I was wondering how min_dist could be updated in a similar fashion in Ruby? Ruby is pass-by-value as I understand so there's no way to pass pointers or anything like that.

Comment: You *can* do recursion in Ruby, but most method calls in the standard C interpreter aren't really optimized for arbitrary depth. That doesn't mean you can't do it; it just means you should make sure there isn't a better idiomatic solution before assuming you need recursion as a generalized solution in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

### Memoization in Ruby

Transcoding functions from one language to another is out of scope for Stack Overflow. However, if your question is how to *structure* memoization-like operations, you have a number of basic approaches in Ruby:

1. Have the **caller** keep track of a local variable, and call the method with the changing value as an argument.
2. Use a **closure** (blocks, procs, or lambdas) to update a variable inherited from an outer scope.
3. Use i**nstance or class variables** to hold the *min_dist* value.
4. Use **global variables (sparingly)** when necessary.

Which is best in any given instance will depend a lot on the semantics of your code. All programming involves trade-offs, so there's no "best" way, but in general start at the top of the list and work your way down to adhere to common OOP practices.

#### See Also

It can be hard to search for more information on this topic without using the right search terms. I'd recommend searching with "ruby" and "memoization" as your key terms, followed by "scope gates" and "closures" if you want to refine your hits, but your mileage may vary.

- [Ruby Memoization and Alternatives](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-memoization-and-alternatives), Thoughtbot
- [Basics of Ruby Memoization](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/), Gavin Miller
- [More links via search engines](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ruby%20memoization)

You might also find it useful to contrast recursion and iteration, as Ruby is great at iteration, but may have some limitations around tail call optimizations and stack depth in some implementations and method calls. You might therefore consider [Enumerator::Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html) as a potential solution for some problems that would otherwise lead to exceeding your stack depth.